# Regex - find the param in a url in any position in the string

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to match a url param and this param's position is not fixed in the uri. It can show up sometime right after the `?` or after the `&`. I need to match `vr=359821` param in the below uri's. How can I do this.

#### Example urls:

```
/br/col/aon/11631?vr=359821&cId=9113
/br/col/aon/11631?cId=9113&vr=359821
/br/col/aon/11631?cId=9113&vr=359821&grid=2&page=something
```

#### Somethings I tried:

I tried to use backreferencing (not sure if this is right approach) but was not successful.
I was trying to group them and may be backreference to find the string within that group.

```
(\/br\/col\/aon\/11631)(\?cId=9113&(vr=359821)) # this matches second url above but not others.
(\/br\/col\/aon\/11631)(\?cId=9113&(vr=359821)).+?\3 # this is wrong I know.
(\/br\/col\/aon\/11631)(\?cId=9113&(vr=359821)).*?\2[vr=359821] # this is wrong
```

Above regex are wrong but my idea was to make it a group and match `vr=359821` in that group. I dont know if this is even possible in regex.

#### why I am doing this:

The final goal is to redirect this url to a different url with all the params from original request in ngnix.

Comment: Perhaps like this with a single capturing group `\/br\/col\/aon\/11631\b.*?[?&](vr=\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/Y4scGE/1  or `\/br\/col\/aon\/11631\?.*?(?<=[?&])(vr=\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/binCZb/1

Comment: sorry, you are correct I can use specific vr number (deleted my comment). I am trying your suggestions now.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, wow!! so far my testing looks good with the regex you provided. Please add it as answer and provide me some explanation so I can learn on how this was approached. All that my mind was thinking is to use grouping and search in the group. Now that I see your answer, I am planning to use vr=xxxx as my unquie identifer in the uri and rest of the param I don't have to even worry about which make my solution much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last 2 patterns that you tried, you are using a backreference like `\2` and `\3`. But a backreference will match the same data that was already captured in the corresponding group.

In this case, that is not the desired behaviour. Instead, you want to match a key value pair in the uri, which does not have to exist in the content before.

Therefore you can match the start of the pattern followed by a non greedy quantifier  (as it can also occur right after the question mark) to match the first occurrence of `vr=` followed by 1 or more digits.

In the comments I suggested this pattern `\/br\/col\/aon\/11631\b.*?[?&](vr=\d+)`, but (depending on the regex delimiters) you don't have to escape the forward slash.

The pattern could be

```
/br/col/aon/11631\b.*?[?&](vr=\d+)
```

The pattern matches

- `/br/col/aon/11631\b` Match the start of the pattern followed by a word boundary
- `.*?` Match any char as least as possible
- `[?&]` Match either `?` or `&`
- `(vr=\d+)` Capture group 1, match vr= followed by 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vHhFpb/1)

From what I read is that nginx uses PCRE. To get a more specific pattern, one option could be:

```
/br/col/aon/11631\?.*?(?<=[?&])(vr=\d+)(?=\&|$)
```

This pattern matches

- `/br/col/aon/11631\?` Match the start of the pattern followed by the question mark
- `.*?` Match any char as least as possible
- `(?<=[?&])` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directy to the left is either `?` or `&`
- `(vr=\d+)` Capture group 1, match vr= followed by 1+ digits
- `(?=\&|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is `&` or the end of the string to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tgdgw9/1)